# Autochange Setting Double Quotes to Single Quotes in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, double-quotes, single-quotes

i explored all over the topics and found out there is no answer for this question,
everyone is using search and replace, that's not the point.
we have to set the default value for attributes when completion is accepted.
I just found out how to change it , so i decided to share with you too.
hope it helps

1. Click the 'File' tab (which is in the upper left corner)
2. Select 'Preferences'> 'Settings'. You can skip 1 and 2 steps by Press 'Ctr + Comma'
3. Search for 'Attribute Default Value'
4. Simply select 'singlequotes' in select field.

So, That's it. Simple and fast

Answer (score 4):

1. Click the 'File' tab (which is in the upper left corner)
2. Select 'Preferences'> 'Settings'. You can skip 1 and 2 steps by
   Press 'Ctr + Comma'
3. Search for 'Attribute Default Value'
4. Simply select 'singlequotes' in select field.

So, That's it. Simple and fast